# How to convert my html Razor view to pdf document without any third-party tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am just new in MVC 4. I have a html Razor view which contain all some table related data.

I just want to convert that view in to pdf document without third-party tool.

Comment: MVC has no PDF functionality.  As such, you must use some kind of third party tool.

Answer (score 7):

In case you are using ASP.NET Core here is my solution: http://nikolay.it/Blog/2018/03/Generate-PDF-file-from-Razor-view-using-ASP-NET-Core-and-PhantomJS/37

### Get HTML string from a Razor view

This step is pretty straight-forward. There is a service called `IRazorViewEngine` in ASP.NET Core which can be injected and then used to get the view. After providing the view with default `ViewDataDictionary` and `ActionContext` we can request the view to be rendered into `StringWriter` which can be easily converted to string. Here is ready-to-use code for getting a string from given Razor view file:

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
}

public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ViewRenderService(
        IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        this.tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = this.serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.GetView(null, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary =
                new ViewDataDictionary(
                    new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    new ModelStateDictionary()) { Model = model };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, this.tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

One important think here: if you use view compilation (pre-compiling views to `YourProject.Web.PrecompiledViews.dll`) then it is important to get the view using the `GetView` method instead of `FindView`. More information [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/191#issuecomment-324435628).

### Generate the PDF file from HTML using PhantomJS

For this task we are going to use a headless browser which will render the HTML (with all CSS and JS included in it). There are many such tools but I will use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API). PhantomJS can save the rendered page to small-sized PDF pretty fast. For the PDF export to work we are going to need a `.js` file which will use the PhantomJS API to tell the tool that we want to export the file:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address,
    output;

console.log('Usage: rasterize.js [URL] [filename] [paperformat]');
address = system.args[1];
output = system.args[2];
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
page.paperSize = { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '0.5cm' };

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

The next thing is to run the `phantomjs.exe` process and pass the `rasterize.js` file along with paths for the HTML file and the output file name for the PDF result. This is done in `HtmlToPdfConverter.cs`:

```
public interface IHtmlToPdfConverter
{
    byte[] Convert(string htmlCode);
}

public class HtmlToPdfConverter : IHtmlToPdfConverter
{
    public byte[] Convert(string htmlCode)
    {
        var inputFileName = "input.html";
        var outputFileName = "output.pdf";
        File.WriteAllText(inputFileName, htmlCode);
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phantomjs.exe")
                            {
                                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                Arguments = string.Format(
                                    "rasterize.js \"{0}\" {1} \"A4\"",
                                    inputFileName,
                                    outputFileName),
                                UseShellExecute = true,
                            };

        var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(outputFileName);

        File.Delete(inputFileName);
        File.Delete(outputFileName);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

If you are going to deploy your application in Azure it is important to have `UseShellExecute` set to `true`.

### Use the code together

Since we now have implemented both `IViewRenderService` and `IHtmlToPdfConverter` we can start using them by first register them in the `Startup.cs` file where your ConfigureServices method should be located (`services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>()` and `services.AddScoped<IHtmlToPdfConverter, HtmlToPdfConverter>()`). Now lets see the code wrapped up together:

```
private readonly IViewRenderService viewRenderService;
private readonly IHtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter;

public DashboardController(
    IViewRenderService viewRenderService,
    IHtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter)
{
    this.viewRenderService = viewRenderService;
    this.htmlToPdfConverter = htmlToPdfConverter;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf(SomeInputModel input)
{
    var model = this.GetViewModel(input);
    var htmlData = await this.viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Dashboard/GetPdf.cshtml", model);
    var fileContents = this.htmlToPdfConverter.Convert(htmlData);
    return this.File(fileContents, "application/pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.NET MVC has no built-in PDF functionality, the only way to convert a Razor view to PDF without a third party tool would be to write the conversion code yourself. This would be a massive undertaking and almost certainly not worth the effort. I would start by [purchasing the ISO 32000-1 reference document](https://www.iso.org/standard/51502.html) and learning everything I could about how the PDF format works. At the time of this answer, the cost is around 200 Swiss francs.